# Splitting string based on delimiter in mysql

Tags: mysql, split

Is there any way to split the following string |RPI;DHCP Letter;IFU;PIL;PCL| into 
|RPI|;|DHCP Letter|;|IFU|;|PIL|;|PCL|?

Any inputs would be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read correctly, and the actual strings in your column do not deviate from the data you showed us, then I think we can simply do a blanket replacement of `;` with `|;|` to get the output you want:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(col, ';', '|;|') AS new_col
FROM yourTable
```

**Output:**

```
|RPI|;|DHCP Letter|;|IFU|;|PIL|;|PCL|
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester